# Does dropping a MySQL table automatically drop that table's indices too?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Does dropping a MySQL table automatically drop that table's indices too?

Comment: That's not as peculiar a question as I thought it was on first reading, actually.  While MySQL's docs don't explicitly mention that a DROP TABLE will drop all the indexes, I think it's implicitly so.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. It drops the indexes. This can be verified:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (foo INT);
CREATE INDEX ix_table1_foo ON table1 (foo);
CREATE INDEX ix_table1_foo ON table1 (foo); -- fails: index already exists.
DROP TABLE table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 (foo INT);
CREATE INDEX ix_table1_foo ON table1 (foo); -- succeeds: index does not exist.
```

You can also verify it by looking in the [information schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/statistics-table.html):

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (foo INT);
CREATE INDEX ix_table1_foo ON table1 (foo);

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.STATISTICS
WHERE INDEX_NAME = 'ix_table1_foo';  -- returns 1

DROP TABLE table1;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.STATISTICS
WHERE INDEX_NAME = 'ix_table1_foo';  -- returns 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Indices are part of their owner table and are freed along with the row data when dropped.

(Foreign-key indices on other tables that refer to it will prevent the table being dropped.)

Answer (score 2):

When a table gets dropped all data, indexes, and linked information will be deleted aswell.
You can look at this as a cascading delete of a row, when you delete a row all the information that was linked to it will be deleted aswell (foreign keys etc)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. Without a table, theres no reason to keep the indexes.

You can confirm this by creating a MyISAM table, and looking in the data folder for `tablename.MYI`. once you drop the table, this file will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-table.html

> All table data and the table
>   definition are removed, so be careful
>   with this statement!